# MySql SELECT many to (many to many)

Tags: mysql, select, many-to-many, sphinx

How can I join two cascading many-to-many relationships ?

I have 5 tables :

```
ITEMS            : id /     name

ITEMS_TAXONOMIES : id /    item_id    / taxonomy_id

TAXONOMIES       : id /  attribute_id / adjective_id

ATTRIBUTES       : id /     name

ADJECTIVES       : id /     name
```

I need a single SELECT to retrieve all associated attribute-adjective pairs for a specific item.

I'm working with Sphinx search engine and I need to look for WORDS associated with the items.

Thank you for your hints...

Comment: Are you doing this to create the sphinx index? Are you saying there's multiple attributes and multiple adjectives for each taxonomy? If so, the only way to get it all in one query is to either group by a field (which will hide records from you) or live with duplicates.  The better option might be to get the attributes and adjectives in secondary queries. (You can even have sphinx do this for you)

Comment: @Cfreak - Yes this is for the sphinx index. No, each taxonomy only has 1 adjective and 1 attribute. But items can have multiple taxonomies and taxonomies belongs to many items. I'm not sure to understand the "group by a field which will hide records from you"... Can you explain a bit, please ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to look for WORDS associated with the items."? Do you mean find a document/item (by searching its name) and then just get a list of 'taxonomies' for the item. Or do you mean you want to search inside the 'attributes/abjectives' names - and return matching documents?

Comment: @barryhunter - I need to search inside both attributes/adjectives names AND item names. Matching document have searched expression in Attributes OR Adjectives OR Item_name.

Comment: I think Sphinx MVA would be great but it seems complexe to me and ideally I want Sphinx to return corresponding items - attributes/adjectives to the results.

Comment: @RémiBarbalat I was referring to the `GROUP BY` functionality of SQL. I don't think it's what you want. Unfortunately I think you'll have to use MVA (which means you can't full-text search them directly). You could set up separate indexes for attributes and adjectives, search those and then filter by the returned results on your main index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copy of my answer already made on the sphinx forum)

The simplest solution I think would be

```
sql_query = SELECT i.id, i.name , \
                    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(at.name,' ',ad.name)) as taxonomies \
                    FROM items i \
                          LEFT JOIN items_taxonomies it ON (i.id = it.item_id) \
                          LEFT JOIN taxonomies t ON (t.id = it.taxonomy_id) \
                          LEFT JOIN attributes at ON (at.id = t.attribute_id) \
                          LEFT JOIN adjectives ad ON (ad.id = t.adjective_id) \
                    GROUP BY i.id \
                    ORDER BY NULL
```

Just to search the words you dont need to use sql_attr_multi. You might get a slight
performance boost doing the indexing via sql_joined_field, but the above is simpler so
try that first. Or you could put the attributes and adjectives in seperate fields. But
the above has the benefit can search "attribute bar" to get a specific taxonomy.

You could stick taxonomy_id into a MVA if you want to group or get back the list of
relevent taxonomies for the document in the result.

Comment: thank_you = answer AS simple AS this;

Perfect answer, thank you very well !